# Sinatra - API - Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, sinatra

We going to develop a little API application in Sinatra. What are the authentication options available to secure the API calls?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Sinatra has no built-in authentication support. There are some gems available, but most are designed for user authentication (i.e. for a website). For an API, they seem like overkill. It’s easy enough to make your own. Simply check the request params in each of your routes to see if they contain a valid API key, and if not, return a 401 error.

```
helpers do
  def valid_key? (key)
    false
  end
end

get "/" do
  error 401 unless valid_key?(params[:key])

  "Hello, world."
end

#  $ irb -r open-uri
#  >> open("http://yourapp.com/api/?key=123")
#  OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized
```

Nothing after the call to `error` will happen if your `valid_key?` method returns false — `error` calls `halt` internally, which stops the request from continuing.

Of course, it’s not ideal to repeat the check at the beginning of each route. Instead, you can create a small extension that adds conditions to your routes:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  register do
    def check (name)
      condition do
        error 401 unless send(name) == true
      end
    end
  end

  helpers do
    def valid_key?
      params[:key].to_i % 2 > 0
    end
  end

  get "/", :check => :valid_key? do
    [1, 2, 3].to_json
  end
end
```

If you just want authentication on all your routes, use a `before` handler:

```
before do
  error 401 unless params[:key] =~ /^xyz/
end

get "/" do
  {"e" => mc**2}.to_json
end
```

Comment: Todd Yandell, thanks a lot for the detailed answer and for your time you spent on it. I really appreciate. It is really helps.

Imran

Comment: Creating a small extension seems overkilling, a before filter is enough, since the latter has option as to which routes to apply. You can also tell that from within the body of the filter by request.path_info.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.secondforge.com/blog/2014/11/05/simple-api-authentication-in-sinatra/ has a slightly more detailed answer that uses user tokens.

This is one step more complicated than an API key, but is necessary if your API needs authentication to log in a user to do things such as editing a name/email/password, or accessing per-user information. (i.e. "private" API actions). You can also revoke/expire user tokens to let people log out, etc.

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  before do
    begin
      if request.body.read(1)
        request.body.rewind
        @request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read, { symbolize_names: true }
      end
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      request.body.rewind
      puts "The body #{request.body.read} was not JSON"
    end
  end

  post '/login' do
    params = @request_payload[:user]

    user = User.find(email: params[:email])
    if user.password == params[:password] #compare the hash to the string; magic
      #log the user in
    else
      #tell the user they aren't logged in
    end
  end
end
```

(It's worth to note that it's more common to read credentials from an HTTP header instead of the JSON body, but the author mentions that.)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Nowadays Token Based Authentication are getting popular.
I'd recommend to use the ruby implementation of the JWT Standard by [**ruby-jwt**](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/master/README.md) for simple authentication and authorization.

```
gem 'jwt'
```